# check the clipboard is disabled in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a javascript function which need data from clipbord.Using only IE. 
But for some clients the clipbord will be disabled IE ->tools->internetoption->security->custom level ,there we can disable the 'Allow programmatic clipboard access'

Time being im checking like `clipboardData.getData('TEXT')==''` feels not good codding.
Is there any way to check  that the clipboard is disabled in browser trough java script .

Comment: Looking at the documentation over at [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535220(v=vs.85).aspx), no method to check if the clipboard is disabled is provided, so I don't think you can do this, closest you'll get is probably to check if you were able to get any data when the user fired an input event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clipboardData.getData('TEXT')==''`  wont work if the programmatic access to the clipboard is turned off.We have only clear data ,set data and get data for clipboard data object.